# Conifer identification

Tags: identification

In Taiwan in winter. This is the only unpruned specimen. fairly commonly grown. The leaf-tips curve upwards. I now think it is likely to be Thuja chinensis possibly 'Globosa'.

[image]

[image: [![] [3](https://i.stack)][3](https://i.stack)

[image: conifer].imgur.com/cmDz0.jpg

Comment: If you add a close up of the needle arrangement, can you also add a pic showing several branchlets on a stem, preferably  held flat or separately from the other branches if you can - I want to see how each little stem is arranged in respect of the others on the same branchlet... no sign of any cones anywhere I suppose? In the top photo that shows the 'needles', they don't seem to have a flattened appearance, they look rounded round the stem - is that the case?

Comment: I will try. the "leaves" are round, not flattened, and branch.

Comment: Looking at the second image, there are 4 areas showing a bit of red - are they part of the tree or just where something else has dropped and  got caught up in the tree?

Comment: No red in tree, leaves from elsewhere. no cones, but one tree has terminal buds now.

Comment: https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/page/19490930#page/218/mode/1up          this should help you find it , it mainly includes the descriptions of the the conifers in the UK but you would be surprised what plants have been stolen in the past and brought back

Answer (score 2):

From the way the leaves clasp the stem and angle outwards slightly, I think it's most likely to be one of the incense cedars, *Libocedrus*. There is a  Taiwanese native incense cedar called *Calocedrus*, and the two are often confused, but I think this is actually *Libocedrus*, most likely *L. chevalieri* or *L.  bidwillii*. You may be able to detect an incense like scent if you crush the leaves, but that depends on how sensitive your sense of smell  is! Further info on *Libocedrus* here https://www.conifers.org/cu/Libocedrus.php

UPDATE: You have mentioned *Thuja sinensis* as a possible ID - whilst I agree the two are remarkably similar, I'm not seeing the flattened sprays/branches which Thuja has, so on balance, I still think it's more likely *Libocedrus.*

Comment: Not any of the three likely Calocedrus spp, still checking others

Comment: Of the five species of  Libocedrus, it might be bidwillii, very similar. Still checking

Comment: Not Chamaecyparis formosensis

Comment: I see why you asked about flat or rounded leaves, not Chamaecyparis taiwanensis.

Comment: I have changed my question to put most likely answer - not sure if this is appropriate.

Comment: Very similar - but Thuja has flattened sprays of leaves, rather like Chamaecyparis does - its why I thought it more likely to be Libocedrus because these sprays are not flattened.

Comment: The "leaves" are cylindrical, but the branchlets are approximately flattened, not as much as  cupressus though.

Comment: thanks for pointing this plant, out the more I learn about it the more amazing it turned out to be ! we have them all over London and I always took time to touch and break a handful. I don't know why I was attracted to this plant probably the smell, colour and shape

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler - its the absence of flattened sprays of leaves that make me think its not Thuja, but the two plants (libocedrus and thuja sinensis) are very similar otherwise. Will edit my answer

Comment: I am finding trees around that look the same. I will try to get a better photo of the juvenile foliage.